# How can I install openjdk 13.x on Centos 7?

Tags: java, repository, centos7, java-11, yum

I have two machines with CentOS 7.x on them, on one I have this (13.x since 2020?):

```
java --version
openjdk 13.0.2 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 19.9 (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 19.9 (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And on another one I have this (11.x since 2023?):

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.20 2023-07-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.20.0.8-1.el7_9) (build 11.0.20+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.20.0.8-1.el7_9) (build 11.0.20+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How can I install version 13 on the other machine too? I cannot see newer version with `yum search`.

On the server with version 13 it says it openjdk is from Epel repo:

```
yum info java-latest-openjdk.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
[...]
https://ookla.bintray.com/rhel/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#51 - "Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate                                                            ."
Trying other mirror.
Installed Packages
Name        : java-latest-openjdk
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 13.0.2.8
Release     : 1.rolling.el7
Size        : 573 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel
Summary     : OpenJDK Runtime Environment 13
URL         : http://openjdk.java.net/
License     : ASL 1.1 and ASL 2.0 and BSD and BSD with advertising and GPL+ and GPLv2 and GPLv2 with exceptions and IJG and LGPLv2+ and MIT and MPLv2.0 and Public Domain and W3C
            : and zlib and ISC and FTL and RSA
Description : The OpenJDK runtime environment.
```

How can I update the other server with this 13.x version?

I want to have latest version because I use some tools that return errors with the 11.x version.

Comment: "I want to have latest version." Java 13 is not the latest version 21 is.

Comment: Java 13 went out of support in March 2020 with the release of Java 14. At the moment the supported Java versions are Java 8 (support until 2026 ~ 2030 depending on vendor and contract), Java 11 (until 2024 ~ 2032), Java 17 (until 2027 ~ 2029) and Java 21 (until 2029 ~ 2031).

Comment: As already said, JDK 13 is obsolete, however you can download it from https://jdk.java.net/archive/

Comment: Thanks the the tips, the java.net url mentions `Mercurial repo`, does anyone know if this would be it ? `mercurial.x86_64 : Mercurial -- a distributed SCM` I found it with Yum, I don't want to break a new server setup

Comment: @adrianTNT You only need Mercurial if you want to checkout the sources, which you shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

`java-latest-openjdk-18.0.2.0.9-1.rolling.el7.x86_64` is provided via the [epel-testing](http://elrepo.org/tiki/HomePage) repo.

```
Name        : java-latest-openjdk
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 18.0.2.0.9
Release     : 1.rolling.el7
Size        : 539 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel-testing
Summary     : OpenJDK 18 Runtime Environment
URL         : http://openjdk.java.net/
Licence     : ASL 1.1 and ASL 2.0 and BSD and BSD with advertising and GPL+ and GPLv2 and GPLv2 with exceptions and IJG and LGPLv2+ and MIT and MPLv2.0 and Public Domain and W3C
            : and zlib and ISC and FTL and RSA
Description : The OpenJDK 18 runtime environment.
```